# Abnormal Advection equation Solution

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

> I am attempting to numerically solve
>   $$
> \frac{\partial y}{dt} + v\frac{\partial y}{dx} = \gamma y
> $$
>   where $v=1$ and $\gamma = 0.1$. The domain is $x \in [0,L]$ and $t \in [0,10]$. We have the boundary conditions $y(0,t)=1$, $y(L,t)=0$ and initial $y(x,0)=0$ for $x>0$. I am looking for an exact analytical solution (if one exists)/ a method to find one, or an accurate numerical solution to compare to?

I have two numerical solutions, one using Forward-Time Central-Space scheme and the other by upwinding. The FTCS one seems to grow quite rapidly, the upwinding one grows but less rapidly. I'm not sure which one is the best and would appreciate another solution to compare to. I've tried matlab by amending "pdex3" (built in example) and that gives the same solution as the FTCS, but I'm not sure whether to trust matlab on this or not. It doesn't help I don't have an intuitive idea behind what the equation should model, so any help on that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Looks solvable analytically by characteristics. The solution will be singular at time $t=L$, so $L<10$ won't be consistent. Otherwise it should just be zero below the diagonal extending from the origin and exponential above that. If you're upwinding in the right direction this should be perfectly accurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\frac{\partial y}{dt} + v\frac{\partial y}{dx} = \gamma y
$$
GENERAL SOLUTION with the method of characteristics :

The set of characteristic differential equations is : $\frac{dt}{1}=\frac{dx}{v}=\frac{dy}{\gamma y}$

The equation of a first characteristic curve comes from  $\frac{dt}{1}=\frac{dx}{v} \quad\to\quad x-vt=c_1$

The equation of a second characteristic curve comes from  $\frac{dx}{v}=\frac{dy}{\gamma y} \quad\to\quad y\:e^{-\frac{\gamma}{v} x}=c_2$

General solution of the PDE expressed on the form of an implicit equation $\Phi(c_1,c_2)=0$ :
$$\phi\left(x-vt\:,\:y\:e^{-\frac{\gamma}{v} x}\right)=0$$
where $\Phi$ is any differentiable function of two variables.

An equivalent form expressing any relationship between the two variables is :
$$y\:e^{-\frac{\gamma}{v} x}=F(x-vt)$$
where $F$ is any differentiable function.

The general solution of the PDE on an explicit form is :
$$y(x,t)=e^{\frac{\gamma}{v} x}F(x-vt)$$

PARTICULAR SOLUTION according to the boundary condition $y(0,t)=1$ :
$$1=e^{0}F(0-vt)\quad\to\quad F(X)=1 \text{ any }X\quad\to\quad y(x,t)=e^{\frac{\gamma}{v} x}$$
But this solution isn't consistent with the other boundary condition $y(L,t)=0$.

PARTICULAR SOLUTION according to the boundary condition $y(L,t)=0$ :
$$0=e^{\frac{\gamma}{v} L}F(L-vt)\quad\to\quad F(X)=0 \text{ any }X\quad\to\quad y(x,t)=0$$
But this solution isn't consistent with the other boundary condition $y(0,t)=1$.

PARTICULAR SOLUTIONS according to both boundary conditions :

This means that the function $F$ isn't a continuous function and involves a singularity. This can be overcome thanks to the Heaviside's $H(X)$ function (step function), with $X=-(x-vt)$ :
$$y(x,t)=e^{\frac{\gamma}{v} x}H(vt-x)$$
On the range $x<vt<L\quad$ the solution is $\quad y(x,t)=e^{\frac{\gamma}{v} x}$

On the range $x>vt\quad$ the solution is $\quad y(x,t)=0$.

Comment: Should $x<vt<L$ be $x\leq vt < L$ to allow the boundary condition $y(0,t)=1$ to be met?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot understand what you mean.

Comment: It appears to be undefined at $vt=x$? Or is that where the singularity is?

Comment: Yes. $x=vt$ is the singularity corresponding to the singularity of the Heaviside's step function. On physical sens, I suppose that could be called a "front" of propagation.

Comment: Ah I see, thank you for your help!